# how to avoid repeated or similar frames in a video when extracting frames from it?

Tags: frames

I think I am getting some repeated or similar frames after extracting the frames from the video. Is there a way to identify and avoid it? and also video duration*FPS is not equal to number of frames I am getting

Comment: Please specify the platform and tools you are working with

Comment: Please show your code. It sounds like a problem with how you read the frames, and you should fix that, instead of cleaning out repeated frames IMO. "similar" frames I don't know why you would exclude, unless you're doing e.g image-recognition and dont want to do it if the frame hasn't changed (much) since last time. Handling video frames can be done easily with OpenCV: Here's a python example, but you can use it with Java and C++ as well: [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#playing-video-from-file)